# how to map dynamic datas for a tree structure

Tags: php, mysql, tree

I need to map dynamic  render datas in tree structure like hierarchy level
like division,name,contents.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smoot-Collapsible-Tree-View-Plugin-with-jQuery-TreeViewJS/ i am using this Plugin.

> $okr_assigned_data = "select distinct uu.division as division from
>   okrs ok inner join objectives o on ok.id = o.okr_id inner join users u
>   on u.id= o.created_by inner join status_conf sc on sc.id = o.status
>   and o.is_deleted = 0 and o.created_by='$loggined_user_id' inner join
>   users uu on ok.user_id = uu.id where (ok.start_date between '$start' 
>   and '$end')  group by uu.id order by o.status asc";

```
$assign_result = mysql_query($okr_assigned_data,$link);
if(mysql_num_rows($assign_result) > 0){
echo '<div class="treeview-container">
  <ul class="treeview">
       <li class="contains-items"> '.$qperiod_search.'';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($assign_result))
    {
        echo '<ul style="display: none;">
        <li class="contains-items items-expanded" id="'.$row[division].'">'.$row[division].'
             <ul style="display: block;" class="'.$row[division].'">
            <li class="contains-items items-expanded">'.$row[names].' <ul>
            <li><div class="obj_list" id=objective_'.$row['objective_id'].' onclick=created_objective_click(this.id)>
 <h3>'. substr($row['ObjectiveName'],0,50 ).'...</h3><p class="status_icon">';?>
<?php 
if($row['status']=='open'){
    echo "<i class='fa fa-folder-open openstatus' aria-hidden='true'></i>".$row['status'];
}
else if($row['status']=='in progress'){
    echo "<i class='fa fa-refresh progress_status' aria-hidden='true'></i>".$row['status'];
}
else if($row['status']=='completed'){
    echo "<i class='fa fa-check completedstatus' aria-hidden='true'></i>".$row['status'];
}
 echo "</p>
 <p class='list_cal'><i class='fa fa-calendar' aria-hidden='true'></i>".date("d-M-Y", strtotime($row['start_date']))." To ".date("d-M-Y", strtotime($row['end_date']))."</p></div>";
?>
<?php echo 
 '</li>
         </ul></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul> ';
        }
    echo ' </li>
  </ul>
</div>';
}
    else{

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "map dynamic datas for a tree structure" ?